# Show (p ∨ ¬q) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q) ≡ ¬q

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

i was looking at the identities, and I was wondering how does this (left hand side) end up becoming not q.

You can use demorgan for  (¬p ∨ ¬q); and negation for (p ∨ ¬q) but how do you show that it equals not q?

Comment: An alternative way is to see that the two sides have identical truth tables.

Answer (score 2):

$(p\vee\sim q)\wedge(\sim p\vee\sim q)=(p\wedge\sim p)\vee\sim q=F\vee\sim q=\sim q$

Comment: how does this use the laws?

Comment: It uses the laws $a\vee(b\wedge c)=(a\vee b)\wedge(a\vee c)$, $d\wedge\sim d={\rm false}$, and ${\rm false}\vee e=e$.

Comment: Does this answer your question, tameer?

Comment: Earth to tameer, come in, please.